# What type of chain is this?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chain

I have approximate measurements only, because I don't have physical access to the device. This chain is driving a small conveyor. The link length is about 9.5mm, ~9mm at narrow width and ~11mm at wide width. The chain is stamped with `890` number.

[image]

Is this a standard size chain? What is that standard, so I can look up a matching sprocket?

Comment: Which chain manufacturers have you checked already?

Comment: I'm getting links to 890 bicycle chains only. Could it be a bicycle chain standard? I have no experience with chains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the photo, I believe the marking is not 890 but **06B**, a standard size for roller chains according to DIN ISO 606 with a pitch of 9,525 mm.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now. Thank you.

Comment: AKA 3/8'  Some things, like screw threads, became different because there was a need for change. Other things are just written differently.